# How to reuse uuid in cql script

Tags: scripting, cassandra, cql, dml

Given the following tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE videos (
    video_id UUID,
    added_date TIMESTAMP,
    description TEXT,
    title TEXT,
    user_id UUID,
    PRIMARY KEY (video_id)
);

CREATE TABLE videos_by_title_year (
    title TEXT,
    added_year INT,
    added_date TIMESTAMP,
    description TEXT,
    user_id UUID,
    video_id UUID,
    PRIMARY KEY ((title, added_year))
);
```

When a new video is created it has to be added to these two tables. The `video_id`needs to be the same in both. On the application side you would solve this programmatically.

I'm writing some cql dml scripts for test environment setup data. So basically a long list of `INSERT` statements.

```sql
INSERT (video_id, ... , user_id) INTO videos VALUES (uuid(), ...);
INSERT (title, ... , video_id) INTO videos_by_title_year VALUES ('Forrest Gump', ... , uuid());
```

In this case the `video_id`'s will be different. Can I in someway reuse a generated `UUID` in cql scripts? Or is the only possible solution to set the id's by hand in my script like below?

```sql
INSERT (video_id, ... , user_id) INTO videos VALUES (7bd6e4ae-0ef2-11e5-9de3-8438355b7e3a, ...);
INSERT (title, ... , video_id) INTO videos_by_title_year VALUES ('Forrest Gump', ... , 7bd6e4ae-0ef2-11e5-9de3-8438355b7e3a);
```

Comment: Which cassandra version are you using ?

Comment: Currently I'm stuck on 2.1

Comment: Can you manage UUID in application side ? Like : generate a UUID, then insert in videos and then insert in videos_by_title_year with the same uuid

Comment: There are multiple solutions to this problem but i'd like to be able to just run a script to fill the db. I can manage UUID on the application side but I'd have to write that code. Or I'd have to have my application fully developed and use the application to get de db in a preferred state and than export to *.csv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know now this is not possible.